# Connect to SSIS from within Management Studio

Tags: ssis

A newbee question: Connect to SSIS from within Management Studio?
I have a running service named: Integration Services 10.0, but from within Management Studio, I don't know how to connect to it, it doesn't appear under the connect button.

Tx.

Comment: What does appear under the connect button?

Answer (score 0):

In Management Studio -> Object Explorer, click on "Connect".  You should have a drop-down with "Integration Services" under it.

Comment: No, I don't have it under the connect button, like I stated in the question

Comment: Thanks for correcting my reading-too-quickly.

Are you using SSMS Express?  Express doesn't have Integration Services support.